# Windows Store App GridView performance

Tags: gridview, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I have a GridView control with a DataTemplate. Inside the DataTemplate is stack panel which contains an image control and a text block. I have bound the Source property of the image control to a function which returns a bitmapimage, which is pre-loaded way before they are requested by the gridview.

The problem is that when you have 10 or more images to display, the app becomes unresponsive for a few seconds while it displays each image, which is bad.

I tried using a virtualizing stack panel which made the UI immediately responsive but then scrolling the gridview became slow but only the first time, once you have scrolled to the end so that all images have been displayed then its fine.

This is on my i7 quad core 2.2Ghz laptop, it will be way worse on a tablet/slate.

The size of the images are no bigger than 640x480, I wouldn't expect that to be too big.

Am i supposed to display thumbnails instead or is there another way to speed up the displaying of images?

Thanks

Comment: Can you share the XAML code of the image template (In my reddit-pictures W8 app i do something similar except that I do not preload the bitmap), my intention is that pre-loading is unnecessary and may drain battery, also performance wise it does not make a huge impact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't be wrong using thumbnails. Anyway, check out the methods of the classes containing the images, because you might be able to choose the scaling method, selecting a faster one (with worse image quality though).